# Iterative function with a substitution

Tags: python, list, for-loop

I am trying to make a for loop which calculates the following

```
#x_i = (1+1/i)x_{i-1}
```

with `x_0=1` I know how to do the first part which is

```
for i in range(1, 3):
    print(1+1/i)
```

I am not sure how to make the `x_{i-1}` work, so it should take the previous iteration and use the calculated value in making the new `x`.

So the final result I am looking for would be a list, looks as follow:

```
#[1, (1 + 1/1), (1 + 1/1)(1 + 1/2),(1 + 1/1)(1 + 1/2)(1 + 1/3),...]
```

Comment: x_0=1, x_1=2 and so on?

Comment: Do you want to end up with a bunch of variables like `x_0`, `x_1`, `x_2` etc or are you only interested in the final value of the calculation?

Comment: @Rohi somehow, for example [1, (1 + 1/1), (1 + 1/1)(1 + 1/2), ... ]

Comment: @Aran-Fey only the numerical answers

Comment: `x_{i-1}` is the previous value of  `x`. Use `x_0=1` as starting point you calculate later values by `x_new = (1+1/i)*x` and update in each step

Comment: Ok, then the duplicate is correct. Store all the intermediate results in a list or dict.

Comment: @Aran-Fey Not sure the duplicate is correct, since he isn't stating he wants to save them, and he could solve this with recursion.

Comment: @Will As you can see, there is some confusion about your question. Please include the desired result in your question. Is it an integer? Is it a list of integers? Is it a bunch of variables holding integers?

Comment: @Aran-Fey I have just done so

Comment: Okay, I've reopened the question.

Comment: @Rohi I don't think recursion is required here, just a simple non-recursive loop should be fine (unless I'm misunderstanding the question ;) ). Generally, recursion should be avoided in Python, unless it's appropriate for the problem domain (like processing recursive data structures) because Python cannot perform tail call optimization, so you get all that extra overhead of slow Python function calls.

Comment: @PM2Ring Didn't know recursion should be avoided, is this an opinion or a widely accepted concept?

Comment: @Rohi It's widely accepted. Somewhat ironically, I have posted a lot of recursive Python code on SO, but that's because I _love_ recursive generators. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope I understood you correctly.

```
initial_value = 1
answer_list = []
answer_list.append(initial_value)
for i in range(1, 3):
    answer_list.append((1+1/i)*answer_list[i-1])

print(answer_list)
```

This should work for you, basically what you want to do is insert the answer into a list in a consecutive manner and multiple in the (index-1).

Comment: The produced list is [0,0,0]

Comment: @Will Accidently set the initial value to 0, change it to whatever value you like.

Comment: when I do print(answer_list.append((1+1/i)*answer_list[i-1])) I get none none none

Comment: @Will what the code does is fill answer_list with values according to your request. After the loop is done, add : print(answer_list)

Comment: @Will Why are you doing that? Just print the final `answer_list` *after* the `for` loop has finished. The `.append` method returns `None`,  which is why "None" is getting printed.